# Error implementing Enity Framework 1.1 using DbContext

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am getting error message as CS0122 'NotNullAttribute' is inaccessible due to its protection level while implementing entity framework in dot net core 1.1.

public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext([NotNullAttribute] DbContextOptions options) : 
        base(options)
        {

```
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using NotNullAttribute, make validation inside of constructor and throw a NullArgumentException

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion..